# Toggle class based on cookie and on toggle checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies, checkbox

I set a cookie successfully in the browser, so that the cookie returned the cookie value `true` when checked, and `false` when unchecked. This cookie changes back and forth on every click of the checkbox.

Here's what I need to do:

1. On page load, it reads cookie, and if cookie value is `true` then it runs `addClass`. If cookie is `false`, then it runs `removeClass`.
2. If the checkbox is manually checked, it runs `addClass`.
3. If the checkbox is manually unchecked, it runs `removeClass`.
4. When it is toggled, it needs to run the add or remove class immediately, not wait until after page load.

Here's what I have, and no errors in console. It's working now, but there's a lag after the page load. How can I fix it to remove the lag?

```
var mytoggle = $.cookie('checkboxValue'); // gets the value saved
if(mytoggle && mytoggle === "true") // (sees if cookie exists and has value of true)
{
    $('body').addClass("myclass");
} else // (if cookie doesn't exist or value is false)
{
    $('body').removeClass("myclass");
}
```

Basically, it sees if there's a cookie with value of `true`, and if so then adds the class. But if there's no cookie or value is `false`, it removes the class. And if the checkbox is toggled while on the page, it adds or removes the class.

How can I get this to check the cookie and add or move class based on the cookie value, and also toggle the class when the checkbox is checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is a string, not a boolean. So, you should use `if (cookie === "true")`. Also, you don't need to check for existence of cookie, it won't be equal to true if not exists.

P. S `var` keyword is legacy and considered as a bad practice. use `let` or `const` instead.

Comment: @user7211 it won't change before page load. Scripts must complete first.

Comment: I need it to add or remove the class from the body before the content below the body loads. And not only that, but I need the toggle to work when I check the box and to happen instantly. Note the page is loaded when I check the box.

Comment: I fixed the toggle part. Added a toggle class when checkbox was changed. Last thing is just to get the class to be added if the cookie exists before the whole page loads.

Comment: Your tip about cookies not being booleans helped. But if you want me to use `let`, could you offer some code to fix it with `let` instead of `var`?

Comment: @user7211, ```let``` will not solve issue if it still appears, but if you want to use it (and you should in modern js) just replace ```var``` with it